# Spotfire: how to access calculated value programatically

Tags: spotfire

So, for example to access/change the "limit data using expression" property corresponding to a barchart I do:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import BarChart
chart1 = Viz.As[BarChart]()
filter = '[CS_AGE] Is Not Null'
chart1.Data.WhereClauseExpression = filter
```

My question is: how can I access the "limit data using expression" property corresponding to a *calculated values* (The ones you create in a text filed using "insert dynamic item>calculated values")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's probably a way to directly modify a control via the API if you know its ID (which you can get by adding the control and then looking at the HTML of its parent textarea), but I don't know what it's called.

that said, if you just need to **change the expression being used for a Calculated Value**, it'd be much simpler to use a Document Property instead. in your script, you can use

```
Document.Properties["MyPropertyName"] = "[Column] > 100"
```

and then in your Calculated Value (and any charts using the same limit), set the data limiting expression to

```
${MyPropertyName}
```

Comment: Thanks> that's a very clever trick. I don't have the office laptop here so I can't check but I'll let you know tomorrow!

Comment: One question: do you need to create "MyPropertyName" in the dashboard? And if yes what kind of property should it be ("input field"?) [for now I have put a small input box but I would prefer if it were hidden to the use]

Comment: yes, you will need to create the property first. go to Edit ... Document Properties ... Properties tab. you do not need to show an input box to have this property.